# NextJs Fetching Copy Text from a data file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am new to NextJs and React. I am coding a website and want the ability to store all copy text (text seen by site users) in a central data-file, and call that into each Section/Component element dynamically.

The reason I am going down this route instead of hard coding static text into each element is that I use a copywriter to edit my text. So I want the ability to send this person a simple file of all site text for editing, without the need to have the entire site code provided or accessed by the editor.

I am thinking I should be using the `getStaticProps` function within NextJs for this purpose:

```
 export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`../data/copy.data.js`);
  const data = await res.json();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { data } // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Together with a Jason file which will hold each Sections copy text as a property. Something like copy.data.js

```
 export const copyText = [
    {
      id: 1,
      section: "Hero",
      Header: "The Heading Text",
      SubHeading: "SubHeading Text",
      Body: "The Body paragragh of text which has a lot more to say"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      section: "Feature",
      Header: "Feature Heading",
      SubHeading: "Feature SubHeading",
      Body: "The Body paragragh of text which has a lot more to say"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      section: "Services",
      Header: "Services Heading",
      SubHeading: "Services SubHeading",
      Body: "The Body paragragh of text which has a lot more to say"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      section: "Service",
      Header: "Service Heading",
      SubHeading: "Service SubHeading",
      Description: "The Specific Service Description paragragh"
    },
];
```

Then in my Component use the data like this:

```
<section sx={styles.section} className="Hero">
  {copyText.map ((copyItem, 1) => (
   <Header sx={styles.header}>{copyItem.Header}</Header>
   <SubHeading sx={styles.header}>{copyItem.SubHeading}</SubHeading>
   <Text sx={styles.header}>{copyItem.Body}</Text>
</section>
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to go, or if there is a simpler method for want I am trying to achieve.

Comment: if you use the fetch function the way you presented you get an error:    "Server Error
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported"

Comment: Ok, so if that is not the method to achieve this, then how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: Below my suggestion... I hope you will be content, best regards !

Comment: @DuncanG Is the data file part of the app or external? In your example it seems to be part of the app, in which case there's no need to `fetch` it, you can simply import the file in your code directly.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If we use the `fetch` function as presented above we will get an error:

> Server Error
>
> TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

[image]

---

To avoid this error, the code should look like this (this is my subjective proposition):
The presentation is as simple as possible, and you can try your hand at adapting the code to your needs.

The `data.js` file is located in project `root` directory. In `id:4` I changed the last item from `Description` to `Body` to be consistent ;-)

---

**index.js** (home page)

```
import ItemsList from "../components/ItemsList.js";
import { copyText } from "../data.js";

export default function Home({ data }) {
  // console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="center">
      <ItemsList data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: { data: copyText }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

---

**ItemsList.js**

```
import Items from "./Items";

function ItemsList({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
      <ul className="center">
        {data.map((event) => (
          <Items
            key={event.id}
            id={event.id}
            section={event.section}
            header={event.Header}
            subHeading={event.SubHeading}
            body={event.Body}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemsList;
```

---

**Items.js**

```
function Items({ id, section, header, subHeading, body }) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <small>{id}</small>
      <h4>{section}</h4>
      <h1>{header}</h1>
      <h2>{subHeading}</h2>
      <p>{body}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Items;
```

---

Of course I added some `css`, but I won't present it because **that's not the point here**.

The output Looks like that:
[image]

*Tested on Win10 "next": "12.0.4","react": "17.0.2",*